# Right align IMG to edge inside a DIV element

Tags: image, html, alignment

I would like to know how to align an `img` to the right edge within a `<DIV></DIV>` element.

I've been using the following code:

`<DIV class=content_mid><img alt="" style="float:right; margin:0px; padding:0px; border:0px; right:0px;" align="right" src=".../img_name.png"></DIV>`

But there is still a bit of space between the image and the right edge of the DIV.

Another note: I'm using a CMS for this, so I don't have access to the CSS. It needs to be done through HTML.

I've also used `position:relative;`, which hasn't worked for me either.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: am not very sure ,but CSS properties will have higher preference than HTML. Moreover u can try position:absolute and in style="position:absolute;float:right;right:0%;".If it still does not work try giving a -ve value in place of 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I  assume parent div element has style "padding".
Try code below,

```
<DIV class=content_mid style="padding:0px!important">
```